# How to set a const value of a file from test file in node js unit testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

I am new to node js because of that facing some difficulties while doing unit testing of my code.
My issue is how to set a const value from testing file.
I have one class (ClassA) having two input param fileName and response, I am reading this file cell by cell and comparing its value in while loop.
I question is how to unit test this scenario.

Example :

ClassA.js

```
function classAFunction(filename,res) { 
try {
        let workbook = XLSX.readFile(filename);
        let sheet_name = 'A';
        let worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheet_name];
        let columnCount =1;
        let columnCountStartWithB = 'B'+columnCount;
        let valueOfColunBCell='';
        if(worksheet[columnCountStartWithB] != undefined ){
            valueOfColunBCell = worksheet[columnCountStartWithB].v; // how to set this value from test file
        } 

        while(true) {

          // some if else based of cell value 
          // increment value of columnCountStartWithB  B1, B2, B3....
         }

}catch (e){
        res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:"Corupted excel file"});
 }
}
```

ClassATest.js

```
beforeEach(function() {

        mock({
            'fake-file-for-testing-only': 'file content'
          });

      });
 afterEach(mock.restore);

it('function Success Case', function(done) {
        let res = {
            status: sinon.spy(),
            json: sinon.spy()
          }

       //how to set valueOfColunBCell  value from this test file
        parsingUpload('fake-file-for-testing-only', res);

        done();
    });
```

Comment: You want to export/import your code modules. Native to node.js is `require` but you can use `esm` (search on npm) for the standard way.

Comment: Thanks George, I do have import this file in test file by require.. but still i am not able to figure it out how to set param value of this file.